# Building cloud engine yaml handler

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I am not a developer and need help configuring app.yaml file for Google Cloud storage. This is what my app.yaml configuration looks like:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /assets/img
  static_dir: assets/img

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /Thank You!_files
  static_dir: Thank You!_files

- url: /.*
  script: box.html
  login: required
  auth_fail_action: redirect

- url: /index.php
  script: box.html
  login: required
  auth_fail_action: redirect

- url: /login
  static_dir: login.php

- url: /login.php
  static_dir: login.php

- url: /main.*

- url: /Thank You!.html
  script: Thank You!.html

- url: /001100110011wine.html(.+)
  script: 001100110011wine.html

- url: /001100110011tomato.html(.+)
  script: 001100110011tomato.html

- url: /001100110011bed.html(.+)
  script: 001100110011bed.html

- url: /001100110011bag.html(.+)
  script: 001100110011bag.html

- url: /001100110011go.html(.+)
  script: 001100110011go.html

- url: /001100110011other.html(.+)
  script: 001100110011other.html
```

But when I click on other.html it keeps redirecting me to the main page box.html.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you're not a developer so I'll divide this answer in parts so I can cover all the things I've found.

**1. Wildcards**

[Wildcards](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-wildcard-characters-939e153f-bd30-47e4-a763-61897c87b3f4) are special characters that can stand in for unknown characters in a text value and are handy for locating multiple items with similar, but not identical data.

The symbol * matches any number of characters. You can use the asterisk (*) anywhere in a character string.

Example: "wh*" matches with **what, white, and why**, but not **awhile or watch.**

Understanding this will help us for the further sections.

**2. About the app.yaml file**

You're having issues with your [app.yaml for PHP 5](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref). This file specifies how URL paths correspond to request handlers. In other words: It's used to tell your app which script will run when an user enteres certain URL's or web address.

For instance, the following:

```
- url: /login.*
   script: login.php
```

can be read as: "Any URL that matches at the end with /login.*, will be handled by the PHP script login.php"

Inside the login.php is part of your app's logic.

**3. Calling certain paths**

A [file path](https://learn-the-web.algonquindesign.ca/topics/paths-folders/) describes the location of a file in a web site's folder structure.

*Absolute File Paths*: It describes the full address(URL) to access an internet file. Example: https://mywebsite.com/web-content/folder/awesome.html

*Relative File Path*: It describes the path of the file relative to the location of the current web page file. Example: folder/awesome.html

**4. Serving static files**

You can also serve files like .png, .jpg or .gif from your app.yaml file. For instance, the following:

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$
```

Can be read as: "All the requests that ended with gif, png or jpg will return the file name with that extension".

There are other ways to call files from your website. For instance, if you write, https://myweb.com/new.html, you might get the file new.html as a response.

**5. Your scenario**

I'd like you to put special attention at the following part in your file:

```
- url: /.*
    script: box.html
```

This can be read as: "Any requests that doesn't match with any of the listed ones", will be redirected to box.html"

Now take a look at:

```
- url: /001100110011other.html(.+)
    script: 001100110011other.html
```

When trying to enter to "/other.html", it doesn't match with the Regular expression of that URL, so you get redirect to `box.html`, the default one.

**6. Recommendations**

- To handle what responses or pages you'd like to see within your app's logic. For instance [Handling HTTP requests from Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests).
- Use the app.yaml file's configurations just to indicate which file you want to use to process or handle the request instead of serving html files from there.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Great! If the info I provided answered your question, please consider accept it :)